# backgroundColor keyword not recognized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm not able to get the "backgroundColor", "Modifier", and "dp" to work. I'm not exactly sure how to search the online documentation for the most up to date changes. I've included a link with the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXxwh.jpg

I'm running on a mac computer big sur. Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 2.
Compose version 1.0.0-alpha08

Answer (score 1):

Box doesn't have backgroundColor property. Try this:

```
@Composable
fun BoxLayout(){
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Blue)
    )
}
```

You also need these imports:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
```

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to search the online documentation to find this information? I couldn't find how to do this or resolve this in the online documentation.

Comment: @fmig Take a look here: 
[link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial)
and here:
[link](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/)

Comment: @fmig You can also look here: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#top_of_page)